# Angular 8: Server is getting garbage instead of file data

Tags: angular, upload, httpclient

I'm using the following code to upload a file to the server.

```ts
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

fileChange(event) {
let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
let file: File = fileList[0];
let body: FormData = new FormData();
body.append('uploadFile', file, file.name);
this.http.put('http://localhost:8000', body).subscribe (data => {console.log ('response',data);});
}
```

I'm using an HTTP server I developed so I can see all data coming from client.
For some reason, after the PUT, server is getting garbage and not the data in the file. 
There is no error message on the chrome terminal.

Comment: The code looks correct. Have you tried to inspect the request in the browser devTools? Can you post the backend data you see?

Comment: Using wireshark I inspected the message sent by client. It contains the following body: Full request URI: http://192.168.14.48:8000/.

Comment: You don't need wireshark for this. It's normal you cannot read the content of the request using that. Open the developer tools on your browser, select the network tab and click on the outgoing request to inspect it.

Answer (score 0):

According to chrome, there is no body.
Following are the request headers:

OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Origin: http://localhost:4200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Referer: http://localhost:4200/timing
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

Thank you,
Zvika

Comment: That is not a PUT, it’s an OPTIONS request. My guess is you have a CORS issue. What is the response to that OPTIONS request?

Comment: You are right. For some reason the stream received in the server starts with OPTIONS.  But in my code I'm calling to http.put (....

Comment: When I changed to .post (instead of .put), the server get a POST request and not an OPTIONS one. According to chrome, the body contains a file. But I cannot see the file contents in the server. Only garbage. Any ideas why can't I use .put ?